# Omitting setup files from docker image build

Tags: c++, docker, visual-c++, installation, dockerfile

I'm creating a docker image capable of running Visual C++ applications.  So the *Visual C++ Redistributable* needs to be installed.  This installer launches some background process that finishes AFTER the installer completes (e.g. 20 sec).

My current solution [ADDs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#add) the redist installer, a test program and a setup script (which runs the installer and repeatedly attempts to run the test program until it succeeds or times out).  The setup script is [RUN](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/reference/builder/#run) from Dockerfile.

**How do I make the redist installer and other setup files available only during docker image building?**  I'd prefer not to have them in the resulting layers.

**EDIT**: Relevant parts of Dockerfile...

```
ADD Dockerfiles C:\Dockerfiles
ADD support\setup.ps1 C:\Dockerfiles\setup.ps1

SHELL ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue';"]
RUN C:\Dockerfiles\setup.ps1
```

Comment: better to post your dockerfile

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to use the docker multi-stage builds.

```
FROM baseimage as builder
ADD test-program /build
ADD setup-script /build
ADD redist-installer /build/
# Run the installer
RUN /build/redist-installer
# Run your setup steps

# Now copy only what you need from the builder image
FROM runtimeimage
COPY --from=builder /result /result
# Your final image doesn't include the setup files
```

More info about usage here: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Unfortunately multi-stage won't fix this problem unless I reverse-engineer what the C++ Redistributable installer does.  It likely saves files to various locations and updates the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I would just remove the files after the setup completes

```
RUN C:\Dockerfiles\setup.ps1 && del C:\Dockerfiles\setup.ps1
```

Add additional files or cleanup commands as needed